# Spring MongoDB Aggregation: Handling 'Invalid Reference' Error with CustomProjectAggregationOperation

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation-framework

I have a group stage shown below, which groups all the documents matching the above stages and creates a group as "userAndFollowingsStory".

```
        GroupOperation groupOperation = Aggregation.group().addToSet("$$ROOT").as("userAndFollowingsStory");
        pipeline.add(groupOperation);
```

After this, I am using a lookup stage with the following pipeline to find all other stories that were not part of that group and create another group as "otherUsersStories".

```
{
  from: "story_doc",
  let: {
    prevGroupIds: "$userAndFollowingsStory._id",
  },
  pipeline: [
    {
      $match: {
        $expr: {
          $not: {
            $in: ["$_id", "$$prevGroupIds"],
          },
        },
      },
    },
  ],
  as: "otherUsersStories",
}


 CustomProjectAggregationOperation customProjectAggregationOperation = new CustomProjectAggregationOperation(query);
 pipeline.add(customProjectAggregationOperation);
```

I am trying to implement this stage using the Spring MongoDB library. Since there is no direct way to write it, I am using the **CustomProjectAggregationOperation** class, which looks like this:

```
public class CustomProjectAggregationOperation implements AggregationOperation {
    private String jsonOperation;
    private String exposedField;

    public CustomProjectAggregationOperation(String jsonOperation) {
        this.jsonOperation = jsonOperation;
    }

    @Override
    public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext aggregationOperationContext) {
        return aggregationOperationContext.getMappedObject(Document.parse(jsonOperation));
    }

}
```

The issue I am facing is that for any subsequent stages, it is showing "**Invalid reference**" for "**otherUsersStories**". For example, the following project stage is giving an invalid reference error:

```
        ProjectionOperation projectionOperationConcat =  Aggregation.project()
                .and("$userAndFollowingsStory")
                .concatArrays("$otherUsersStories")
                .as("infiniteStories");

        Aggregation mainAggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(pipeline);
        AggregationResults<StoryDoc> mainResults = mongoTemplate.aggregate(mainAggregation, CollectionNames.STORY, StoryDoc.class);
```

How can I resolve this "Invalid reference" error for other user stories in subsequent stages?